# How should I use $in for a MongoTalk query?

Tags: mongodb, smalltalk, pharo

I need to perform a selection of MongoDb documents using `$in` as documented https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

`{ field: { $in: [<value1>, <value2>, ... <valueN> ] } }`

I've tried with this but

`conditions := { 'conditionIds' -> {'$in' -> [ 'uQqazzdwSYsEmqGNp' ] } asDictionary } asDictionary.
    collection := database collectionAt:  'users'.
    collection query: [ :q | q where:  conditions ].`

I saw that `MQInCondition` exists, which is very promising, but I've failed to find any example in the tests or project docs. Anyone knows how to use it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can either use the 1:1 mapped javascript syntax (e.g. transmitting directories) or use MQuery to "automagically" build queries.

Sample below:

```
mongo := Mongo default open.
db := mongo databaseNamed: 'playground'.
col := db getCollection: 'test'.

col add: {'field' -> 'value1'} asDictionary;
    add: {'field' -> 'value2'} asDictionary.

col select: { ('field' -> { '$in' -> #('value1' 'value2') } asDictionary)}. "The javascript way"
col select: [ :each | (each at: 'field') in: #('value1' 'value2') ] "The Smalltalk way"
col select: [ :each | (each field) in: #('value1' 'value2') ]. "Even Smalltalkier :-)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You mistook [ ] as Array initializer while in smalltalk it is for blocks. Just use {} instead.

```
collection query: { 'key' -> {
    '$in' -> {  val1 . val2 } } asDictionary } asDictionary
```

When using the query: aBlock version then you use smalltalk expressions inside block. But the amount of expressions you can use is pretty limited and does to this date not support $in

Comment: Thanks Norbert. But we do have `MQInCondition`, what would it need to make it work?

Comment: For the record: I needed the values of the query to be parametrized (it's an array that comes as argument) so I can't really use `{ val1. val2 } asDictionary`

Comment: So just put the array instead of { val1. val2 }.

Comment: Ah, I don't know about $in. It seems you just need to use the #in: selector. Like in : MQQueryBuilder new buildQueryFor: [ :each | each label in: { #a . #b } ]

Answer (score 1):

I've found a syntax error on the array of the argument in my previous attempt and the idea was generally right. This is the one that works:

`conditions := { 'conditionIds' -> {'$in' -> #('uQqazzdwSYsEmqGNp') } asDictionary } asDictionary.
    collection := database collectionAt:  'users'.
    collection query: [ :q | q where:  conditions ].`